# Skipping header view in case of mobile using anchors

Tags: html, css, user-interface, seo

I have a website that supports responsive design where the header is a bit big having the menu, social media icons, search and filters, logo...etc.

The header is not fixed to top when I open the site on mobile, it goes away by scrolling.

The problem is that the space it takes keeps the important page content to view when the page first lands and it is not a good user experience the way it is now.

I have in mind to add some anchors and access the main div(s) right below the header but this requires to append anchors to all links in the website (or 90% of the links at least) to reference specific div ids:

```
<a href="page1/#breadcrumb">Page 1</a>
<a href="page2/#breadcrumb">Page 2</a>
```

where `breadcrumb` is a common container for website body.

Is there a better practice to solve this problem?

Does adding the same anchor to different links affect SEO negatively in a way or another?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand … you want to skip the whole header part, so that users can directly jump to the main content, right? Why can’t you just use something like `<a href="#main-content">Jump to main content</a>`?

Comment: @unor Yes you are right this is what I want. Adding a jump section sounds fine, I also have a problem with the pagination section, the user on mobiles scrolls down to the pagination and want to see the next page in pagination, when the page loads again on mobile, he gets to see the header and then reach the pagination by scrolling.. That was my initial question, to get to the content directly using anchors, is it best practice responsively? And how does it affect SEO